# get every name of month components in swift

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I want to get an array of months from Calendar component in swift. Like:

```
var monthComponents = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar" ..]
```

But I'm only able to get whether the current date or convert a certain date format to string. So, how could I get all month components (month names). Please suggest me with a simple way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `DateFormatter` class has what you need:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let monthComponents = formatter.shortMonthSymbols
```

See the docs for `DateFormatter` to see all of the other related methods for getting other various symbols.

Or as of iOS 10/macOS 10.12 you can use `Calendar`:

```
let monthComponents = Calendar.current.shortMonthSymbols
```

Comment: Okay, so if we're developing a project for deployment target less than iOS 10 than can we use  Calendar ?

Comment: If your deployment target is iOS 9 or earlier then you can't use `Calendar` because `shortMonthsSymbols` doesn't exist prior to iOS 10. Use the `DateFormatter` version.

Comment: So, I cannot use calendar object in any way? 
I was trying to use as: if let oneYearAgo = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Year, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: []){}
..where, calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar(), currentCalendar = NSDate()

Comment: Sure, you can use Calendar. You just can't use the `Calendar shortMonthSymbols` under iOS 9 or earlier.

Comment: You are asking a completely new question. If you can't find an answer after some research, post a new question specific to your new issue.

Comment: Its working fine if I can use calendar other components. :) Thanks!